# Prove universal gate math

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I tried to deal with this question:
    $$F(a,b,c,d) = (a'+b'+c')\oplus bcd$$
While I asked to prove that F with the constant '$0$' is universal gate.

I know that to prove that some function is universal gate so i need to simplify the function and show that the function is using NAND and NOR gates (that contains not, or, and).

Is thats what I need to prove here?

Comment: Is the second $b'$ really supposed to be a $b'$?

Comment: No, i fix it - should be not C

Comment: How about ${\rm Nand}(X, Y) = F(X, Y, Y, 0)$ ? I believe that is enough to establish $F$ as a universal gate.

Comment: But how do you chose the X, Y, Y, 0?

Answer (score 1):

No. Take a look at the definition of universal set (of some gates and constants) again. It means that every propositional formula can be computed via a circuit that uses **only** gates and constants from such a set. So "i need to simplify the function and show that the function is using NAND and NOR gates" is false. The nand gate is universal already, so everything can be implemented using it alone, so proving that $F$ can be implemented using the nand gate says nothing at all about $F$.

Comment: So what you suggest? @Danielv commented F(X, Y, Y, 0) but i didnt understand why.

Comment: @motis10: What do you think? Since you aren't familiar with this, you ought to do it directly to get used to it. You need to prove that you can implement every propositional formula using only $F$. Do it! Every propositional formula is made up of atoms and connectives. If you can implement every connective using $F$, then you're done!

Comment: So i need to try all the options? And prove them all or just find 1 and thats prove it?

Comment: @motis10: I don't understand your question. Can you or can you not implement the AND,OR,NOT gates using $F$?